# Angular2 AngularFire Auth testing with Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to write a unit test for my Component, but I can't spy on the AngularFire class correctly.

```
//Component

  import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
  })
  export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
      public angularFire: AngularFire
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.angularFire.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        // do stuff
      });
    }
  }
```

My test is simple, I'm trying to spy on the Auth class to turn the subscribed mock user.

```
//Test
let AngularFireMocks = {
  auth: jasmine.createSpy('auth')
};

AngularFireMock.auth.and.returnValue(Observable.of({ uid: 'ABC123' }));

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        HeaderComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AngularFire,
          useValue: AngularFireMocks
        }
      ],
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
});
```

I get the error;

```
this.angularFire.auth.subscribe is not a function
```

I don't understand why, I used this same kind of logic when testing an async service, but when doing the same for a component it doesn't appear to work.

I've also tried returning different types of observables - like using Observable.create instead of Observable.of as well as mocking out the auth class and spying on the subscribe function and returning an object, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `auth` is a property, not a function, but `createSpy` returns a function.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `auth` isn't called as a function (`auth()`), it's accessed as a property. `and.returnValue` probably only works on functions (and when the function is called). You could make it work by just doing

```
let AngularFireMocks = {
  auth: Observable.of({ uid: 'ABC123' })
};
```

and just forget the spy.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't think of that. Works great!

Comment: The Auth method can also call a function "logout" (among others).

How do I get it to return the observable but also leave it open to call the logout function?

Comment: Maybe just spy on the `subscribe` function of the `auth`. `auth: { subscribe: jasmine.createSpy('subscribe')`. I think there is a way to get the arguments from the spy when it's called. The argument will be a function, and just call it with the whatever you want to pass to it

Comment: There are so many different ways you can handle this. There's not only one way. You may just need to restructure you mock completely